# What is the file format

Tags: raster, geography-data-type

I have been sent a text-file (see below) with '.txt' extension. I would like to process it in ArcGIS or any other GIS-tool. Unfortunately I do not know how to automatically load the file as ArcGIS does not recognize the file format. So far I have used the add XY-data tool, but I will have to add all metadata (for many files).

```
NAME III (version 6.3)                                          
 Title:               ENHANCE_TEST
 Run time:            0707UTC 21/05/2015
 Met data:            NWP Flow.Global_PT2_flow
 Start of release:     1800UTC 14/04/2010
 End of release:       1800UTC 15/04/2010
 Release rate:        4.6627776E+07g/s
 Release location:    19.3700W   63.3700N
 Release height:      5833.000m asl +/- 4167.000m
 Forecast duration:   120 hours
 X grid origin:         0.0000000E+00
 Y grid origin:         -90.00000    
 X grid size:                  640
 Y grid size:                  480
 X grid resolution:     0.5625000    
 Y grid resolution:     0.3750000    
 Number of fields:              25

               ,                   ,                   ,                   ,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,                VOLCANIC,
               ,                   ,                   ,                   ,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,            VOLCANIC_ASH,
               ,                   ,                   ,                   ,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,    006 hr time averaged,  006 hr time integrated,  006 hr time integrated,  006 hr time integrated,
               ,                   ,                   ,                   ,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,       Air Concentration,          Dry deposition,          Wet deposition,        Total deposition,
               ,                   ,                   ,                   ,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m3,                    g/m2,                    g/m2,                    g/m2,
               ,                   ,                   ,                   ,      From FL000 - FL025,      From FL025 - FL050,      From FL050 - FL075,      From FL075 - FL100,      From FL100 - FL125,      From FL125 - FL150,      From FL150 - FL175,      From FL175 - FL200,      From FL200 - FL225,      From FL225 - FL250,      From FL250 - FL275,      From FL275 - FL300,      From FL300 - FL325,      From FL325 - FL350,      From FL350 - FL375,      From FL375 - FL400,      From FL400 - FL425,      From FL425 - FL450,      From FL450 - FL475,      From FL475 - FL500,      From FL500 - FL525,      From FL525 - FL550,          Boundary layer,          Boundary layer,          Boundary layer,
         X grid,             Y grid,          Longitude,           Latitude,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,      2200UTC 17/04/2010,

       1.500000,         356.500000,           0.281250,          43.312500,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.21971285E-06,          0.28804527E-05,          0.35517323E-05,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,
       1.500000,         357.500000,           0.281250,          43.687500,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.36306966E-06,          0.14946055E-05,          0.21932854E-06,          0.00000000E+00,          0.28790544E-05,          0.35703024E-05,          0.49161085E-05,          0.33067158E-05,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,
       1.500000,         358.500000,           0.281250,          44.062500,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.14613357E-05,          0.18284396E-06,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.45010469E-06,          0.11223924E-05,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,
       1.500000,         359.500000,           0.281250,          44.437500,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.51991611E-06,          0.31933364E-05,          0.18260474E-06,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.48921193E-05,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,
       1.500000,         360.500000,           0.281250,          44.812500,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.13139447E-05,          0.15333062E-05,          0.55731643E-05,          0.33343988E-05,          0.11096894E-05,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.13499933E-05,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,
       1.500000,         361.500000,           0.281250,          45.187500,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.13255150E-05,          0.42389831E-06,          0.67642318E-05,          0.13047811E-04,          0.18184770E-06,          0.39584972E-06,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,
       1.500000,         362.500000,           0.281250,          45.562500,          0.26978432E-05,          0.22520110E-05,          0.50884732E-05,          0.21446236E-04,          0.25799594E-04,          0.15634747E-04,          0.19254403E-05,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.00000000E+00,          0.21346756E-02,          0.00000000E+00,          0.21346756E-02,
```

Comment: Looks like an IRIS format https://github.com/SciTools/iris-test-data/blob/master/test_data/NAME/NAMEIII_timeseries.txt & http://www.vaisala.com/en/meteorology/products/weatherradars/Pages/IRIS.aspx

Comment: For using the IRIS format in QGIS please see https://github.com/SciTools/iris